# XLL doesn't get loaded automatically

Tags: excel, xll

Typically, when one activates an XLL for the first time in Excel's add-ins dialog, it gets reloaded automatically next time one launches Excel. There is no need to activate it again after it has been activated once.

Now I have an XLL that I have built myself. The problem I'm having is that on my desktop this XLL does not show the expected behaviour explained above: it does not automatically get reloaded after the first activation (and successful use!).

I'm on Windows 10, Office 365/64bit.

Please note that the exactly same XLL reloads as expected on my laptop (same environment as desktop).

Please also note that other XLL's reload as expected on the desktop.

In short:

- XLL on desktop: doesn't reload
- XLL on laptop: does reload
- Other XLL's on desktop: do reload

Does this ring a bell with anybody out there? Or is there someone with great Excel intuition? Thanks a lot in advance, I have already been losing a lot of time with this... :(

-Mario

Comment: Is it getting disabled on the desktop?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "disabled". I can always activate it manually, and then it will work just fine. But it gets "deactivated" (maybe that's what you mean), i.e. the corresponding box in the add-ins dialog is unchecked, but I don't know when that happens.

Comment: If it's becoming unchecked in the add-ins dialog, I'd suspect a permissions issue with your registry.

Comment: I'm not using the registry, I never did for many years and things worked just fine. Actually I just compiled an older version of the XLL, and that older version behaves as expected. So I hope that by comparing the old and the current version I can find out what the problem is.